# What is the macOS (10.14.6) equivalent of --exclude in du?

Tags: disk-space

What is the macOS (10.14.6) equivalent of --exclude in du ?

```
du -hs --exclude=./node_modules/
du: illegal option -- -
usage: du [-H | -L | -P] [-a | -s | -d depth] [-c] [-h | -k | -m | -g] [-x] [-I mask] [file ...]
```

Comment: "-I mask
             Ignore files and directories matching the specified mask." If you need GNU behaviour, install coreutils via brew and invoke `gdu` (like `gfind` or `ggrep`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had luck on MacOS 10.15 with the following:

```
du -I System -I private -I Library
```